# Given a user id, get all their channels with recipients and last message preview?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is to get back a list of group chats like you'd see on any chat app.

The example shows direct messages, but technically 3+ users could join the chat channel. Assume there is no user table.

I want to be able to pass in some_user and "get all channels some_user is participating in, with the channel members that are not some_user (the recipients), and last message sent to the channel for a preview, ordered by last message created_at desc".

```
channel
---
id(pk)

channel_user
---
channel_id(fk) | user_id

message
---
id(pk) | channel_id(fk) | sender_id | text | created_at
```

---

```
channel
---
1
2

channel_user
---
1 | "Elon"
1 | "Mark"
2 | "Steve"
2 | "Elon"

message
---
3 | 1 | "Elon" | "AI will destroy us all" | timestamp(late)
4 | 1 | "Mark" | "No it won't"            | timestamp(later)
5 | 2 | "Steve"| "Sup Elon"               | timestamp(latest)
```

---

Pass in user "Elon" and get something like:

```
channel_id | recipient(s)             | last_message  | last_message_sender | last_message_created_at
---
2          | "Steve" or ["Steve",...] | "Sup Elon"    | "Steve"             | timestamp(latest)
1          | "Mark" or ["Mark",...]   | "No it won't" | "Mark"              | timestamp(later)
```

Comment: How would you want that result set structured. SQL returns rows and columns, but you seem to want something more like an object. Can you share some sample data and your desired results?

Comment: @JNevill Hope I made that clearer. Basically this is for a list of messages you've received that you'd see on any chat app.

Comment: Gotcha! That really does help. I was making some wrong assumptions from your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like the following should get you in the ballpark:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
        SELECT m.channel_id, m.sender_id, m.text, m.created_at, row_number() over (PARTITION BY m.channel_id ORDER BY created_at desc) as message_rank
        FROM    
            channel_user cu
            INNER JOIN message m ON 
                cu.channel_id = m.channel_id
        WHERE
            cu.user_id = 'Elon'
            AND m.user_id <> 'Elon'
) sub
WHERE sub.message_rank = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Never seen that syntax before, but I just learned what a window function is. :)

Comment: Now you are dangerous!